# Safari for MAC: html placeholder not fading up

Tags: javascript, html, safari, cross-browser, placeholder

**Safari for Mac-book version: *10.0.1***

After loading the web page in safari the text in `placeholder` attribute of html input tags are **mixing (overlapping)** with the actual `value` of that input element, whereas it is being replaced by the value in other browser as expected behavior.

It only disappears after `focus` (clicking) on that element.

*NOTE: The input values are being filled up by JavaScript.*

This is a part of big web page which includes jquery/bootstrap:

```
<div class="form-group bsd-hide">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <label for="ESSID" class="control-label">SSID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input name="ESSID" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="ESSID" placeholder="SSID" onkeyup="sameasabove()" tabindex="12">
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript filling this value:

```
function initFill(obj) {
    if (obj !== false) {       
        var obj2G = obj["wl1"][0];    

        jQuery('[name="ESSID"]').val(obj2G.essid);

....
}
```

[image]

Comment: Negative voters thanks for down voting and impatient job done. now if the code and image sample is satisfactory to know the issue. can you try to solve it and answer it too?

Comment: Same problem mate...

Comment: I am having the exactly same problem. Did you find any fix @AmitShah ?

Comment: nope, i wonder why? some people were so fast and eager to downvote this question without the example earlier. but none of them i found interested to solve this.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. I've upvoted your post.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle someone created to reproduce the issue... https://jsfiddle.net/gkatsanos/2355m5ds/